# Get a list of Devices from IBM BLUEMIX IoT Foundation

Tags: php, ibm-cloud, mqtt

How can I get the list of devices in IOT Foundation using MQTT and PHP.
I tried this Code:

---

```
<?php
require("../phpMQTT.php");
$config = array(
  'org_id' => 't9m318',
  'port' => '1883',
  'app_id' => 'phpmqtt',
  'iotf_api_key' => 'my api key',
  'iotf_api_secret' => 'my api secret',
  'device_id' => 'phpmqtt'    
);

$config['server'] = $config['org_id'] . '.messaging.internetofthings.ibmcloud.com';
$config['client_id'] = 'a:' . $config['org_id'] . ':' . $config['app_id'];
$location = array();
// initialize client
$mqtt = new phpMQTT($config['server'], $config['port'],     $config['client_id']); 
$mqtt->debug = false;

// connect to broker
if(!$mqtt->connect(true, null, $config['iotf_api_key'],  $config['iotf_api_secret'])){
  echo 'ERROR: Could not connect to IoT cloud';
    exit();
}
```

---

But I don't know What should I put for subscribe TOPIC.

Then I change the code and tried to use HTTP instead of MQTT:

$UserPass  = $config['iotf_api_key'].':'.$config['iotf_api_secret'];

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 't9m318.messaging.internetofthings.ibmcloud.com');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD,  $UserPass);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Accept: application/json','Content-Type: application/json'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$arr = json_decode($output,true);
echo $arr;
```

But it does not work!

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't get a list of devices via MQTT, but you can use the HTTP API to list all the devices.

You can get all devices with:

https://docs.internetofthings.ibmcloud.com/swagger/v0002.html#!/Bulk_Operations/get_bulk_devices

Or filter by deviceType with:

https://docs.internetofthings.ibmcloud.com/swagger/v0002.html#!/Devices/get_device_types_typeId_devices

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

I changed the Code to this:
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 't9m318.messaging.internetofthings.ibmcloud.com');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD,  $UserPass);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Accept: application/json','Content-Type: application/json'));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
    $output = curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close($ch);$arr=json_decode($output,true);
But it does not work!

Comment: All you have passed to curl is the server, not the path to the endpoints I've listed, so you will not get anything useful